# finite covering space of non-orientable surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Let $X_k$ the connected sum of k projective planes. I wonder about necessary and sufficient conditions to know wheter there exists a covering $\pi: X_{k'} \to X_k$ if k and k' are integers.

A necessary condition is that the euler characteristic of $X_{k'}$ has to be multiple of the euler characteristic of $X_k$, so is the sufficient condition what it's more difficult.

The case of orientable surfaces is easy, but this is more difficult I think, and I can't find it anywhere.

I would appreciate any hint about this.

Edit: when I wrote $X'_k$ I meant $X_{k'}$, so $X_{k'}$ is another connected sum of projective planes.

Comment: What is $X_k'$? A different non-orientable surface?

Comment: Question already answered here 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146847/sufficient-condition-for-coverings-between-non-orientable-surfaces